Differences between HTML injection methods?
Is there a difference between html element injection methods? In terms of efficiency, ease of use, security...?
Usually, when I inject html, I do something like this:
const myDivInnerHtml = '<div><div>All the elements and etc...</div></div>';
const myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.id = "myDiv";
myDiv.innerHTML = myDivInnerHtml;
$('.document_element').append(myDiv);

Though I have at times done it more directly, like so:
const myDivInnerHtml = '<div id="myDiv"><div><div>All the elements and etc...</div></div></div>';
$('.document_element').append(myDivInnerHtml);


This is a simple process and nets me the results I need, but it can make it hard/annoying to navigate the code if myDivInnerHtml has a lot of elements (like when making a UI for a script, needing different tabs, buttons, and the like).

HTML injection is getting blocked on more and more popular modern sites that use trustedHTML API, so the most reliable method is to not use any html at all. Instead, use a library that builds the necessary JS code from an html template/string. There are many big libraries (Vue, React) that aren't a good choice for userscripts, but there are also tiny libraries without any runtime, i.e. they only produce the vanilla JS code, e.g. maybe Svelte and some others.

Avoid HTML injection whenever you can and use .createElement() to create and append elements together. It's more code, but at the end of the day works out to be more scalable (IMO) and secure.

@woxxom Thank you, I will look into options such as Svelte!

@ScottMarcus would this still be viable when needing to add 12+ elements to a page? I'm concerned about performance too

@woxxom Modern svelte requires a (small) runtime as well afaict, and using templates for html it probably also uses innerHTML

@user26839name Unless you're talking about thousands of elements, there won't be a noticeable performance difference

"when needing to add 12+ elements to a page" - if this is a core problem, please add all such clarification to your question by editing it. "12+" elements might not be a problem if this means 13 elements, but it might be if it means 1k, 10k, 100k elements. But what keeps you from checking this in a small example on your own?

@NicoHaase Sorry, I don't understand the last sentence of your comment very well. I should clarify: I work on small projects, the amount of divs stays under 100

Then why not run your code with the one version (from your first snippet) with ~100 divs, check the execution time, and then refactor your code to use the second version, run it again with ~100 divs and see what happens? That's so little code that this experiment should not take too much time. Whether this means something for production websites is a different question, but that depends on so many other things you haven't told us that there is no specific answer to be given

@user26839name Manually creating DOM elements with .createElement() shouldn't be any more intensive than with injection because, either way, new DOM elements need to be created. In fact, by creating elements individually with .createElement you can build up an element hierarchy outside of the DOM and then inject it when you are ready, which oftentimes allows you to build up dynamic values without affecting the DOM at all.

There are some differences between the methods:

Using createElement and innerHTML is better if you want more control. You can tweak the element before adding it, and it’s a bit safer for dynamic content since you can validate it. It’s also easier to work with modular or reusable code this way.

Direct injection with innerHTML is simpler and a bit faster, but it can get messy if the HTML gets big. It’s also less secure if the content is user-generated because it’s more prone to XSS attacks.


If your HTML is complex or you need to reuse parts, stick with createElement. For small static stuff, direct injection is fine, but always sanitize your content if there’s any user input involved. And for bigger projects, consider a templating library or framework like React or Vue for better structure!
When you use innerHTML, the browser must re-parse all existing HTML inside the element and rebuild the DOM tree.
In some occasions, it can case issues e.g. re-parsing can cause references to previously constructed DOM elements to become invalid, as the browser essentially reconstructs the DOM tree from scratch for the element.
If the parent DOM element has many children it can also cause performance issues.
Using appendChild to add a new element avoids re-parsing the existing content. Instead, the new node is appended directly to the DOM tree, which is more efficient, and does not break functionality on previously parsed elements.

This sounds really familiar, and doesn’t really apply to the example in the question (more like a different question that used .innerHTML +=). Did you copy it from somewhere?

@Ry- thanks for pointing out my mistake. I overlooked the first part of the question that was using jquery selector to append the HTML content to the parent element

Alright, now innerHTML is safer for dynamic content since you can validate it, but innerHTML is less secure for user-generated content because it’s more prone to XSS attacks. Is this AI-generated? AI-generated content isn’t allowed on Stack Overflow.

no it's not AI generated, you can find details on security risks of using innerHTML on mozilla documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
under security considerations
